# Calling main method class from another java class

Tags: java, function, netbeans

I have two java classes.One in which my GUI is written and the other class in which i have implemented an interface(call it class 2).My project starts from the main method of GUI.I want to send a string to my GUI class from the class 2 for displaying it in the Text area but nothing is happening.

As my main gui class is

```
           public class GraphicalInterface extends javax.swing.JFrame{
              //I have created a function over here for displaying string in text area

              public void show1(String name)
                {
                  jTextArea1.setText(name);

                 }

                   //buttons code
                         public static void main(String args[]) {
                  //code
                   }
            }
```

I have created an object of this class in my class 2 like below

```
                    GraphicalInterface b=new GraphicalInterface();
                    b.show1("pear");// it does not allow me to write this statement
```

Please help me out that how can i call main method class from another java class.Thanks.

Comment: "// it does not allow me to write this statement" What do you mean by this? Are you getting a compilation error? If yes then please let us know what

Comment: can you provide the class 2 code ? where exactly are you executing these 2 stmts ?

Comment: @Grrrrr:   when i write b. and wait for the functions to appear from which i can choose the show1 but show1 doesn't appear

Comment: @ Rocky: I have written these 2 lines of code in my class which is an implemenation of java interface

Comment: In such a case I would try clean and build on my machine, or even make sure that there arnt two GraphicalInterface classes in two different packages. Is it possible that in you class 2 you are using a GraphicalInterface class which is from completely different package?

Comment: @deporter How to do that? and secondly why to do that? :s

Answer (score 1):

You may be trying to call this code outside of a constructor or method (or initializer block) and in Java, this can't be done. Instead call this code inside of a method or constructor.

Comment: I think that you're on to something, that your answer is correct. I hope you don't mind my edit for clarity. For many English is not a first language and so we try to encourage posters to avoid using non-standard abbreviations but instead to write out answers in full English sentences.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Not at all..  Thanks for editing my post

Comment: @NIVESH SENGAR  : are u saying that i have to create a constructor in class 2 for calling the method of GraphicalInterface?

Comment: yes...  And if you want to call that method why not you take tha class2 for your starting point(main should be in class2)

Comment: @NIVESH SENGAR : Actually my application starts with the GUI(filechooser) therefore the main method is there

Comment: so call the method from the constructor so when you initialize object of this class it will call the show1 method....

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you have a design problem in your project. Let me expain. You say you have a GUI class **"GraphicalInterface"** which holds the main method which is the starting point of an application in Java. You say you need to call the main method of this class in another class,
**"your class 2".** If so why isn't the place belonging to the **"main method"** of your application in which you try to call this GUI's main method. Call GUI's main method x(), let the place that you call x() belong to the main method.

If you need to operate on the GUI's fields in another classes and also keep the main method still there, then I suggest you to apply **Singleton Pattern** to your GUI class. In that way you 
will be able to refer the only instance of your public singleton class everywhere in your application.

```
public class GraphicalInterface extends javax.swing.JFrame
{
              public String textAreaContent;

              public getX()( return textAreaContent;)
              public setX(String s)( this.textAreaContent = s;)

              public void show1()
              {
                  jTextArea1.setText(this.getTextAreaContent());
              }
              public static void main(String args[]) 
              {        
                 //code
              }
 }
```

From your other class:

```
 GraphicalInterface b=new GraphicalInterface();
 b.setX("text area content");
 b.show1();
```

Comment: My results are coming in class 2 which i want to display in textarea, whose code i have written in GraphicalInterface class.

Comment: So you should put public methods (getter and setter) for the text which is to be displayed in textarea. You can set this text from your class 2, then set it to the textfield in your GUI class. I'm addding my answer some snippet.

Comment: @ superdeporter :Can u please elaborate that how will i apply getter and setter methods in my case.

Comment: @Zara Read my post again, I have included some code snippet for you.

Answer (score 0):

No, the best solution is not to do this, and if you feel you must, it is likely because your design is somehow broken. Instead write your code so that your classes are true OOPs classes that interact in an intelligent way (low coupling, high cohesion), and to only need one main method.

Also, you state:

```
GraphicalInterface b=new GraphicalInterface();
b.show1("pear");// it does not allow me to write this statement
```

What do you mean by "it does not allow me to write this statement"? Does the Java compiler give a compilation error?  Does the JVM throw an exception? Does the JVM reach out of your monitor and slap you in the face? Please let us know all the details necessary to be able to help you.

Comment: when i write b. and wait for the functions to appear from which i can choose the show1 but show1 doesn't appear

Comment: @Zara: Check that you don't have two versions of the GraphicalInterface class, or that you haven't removed all previous class files and recompiled all files. But the solution is most definitely  **not** to call the main method from two classes. Currently you're barking up not only the wrong tree, but the wrong tree in a completely different forest.

Comment: I just have 1 version of  GraphicalInterface class and i haven't removed the previous class files..  :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a method in `class2` and call it from your `main` method.

**Sample code class1**

```
public class Test1 {
    public void show(String ab){
        System.out.println(ab);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test2.Test2();
    }
}
```

Above code i create a class `Test1.java` like your `class1` and create a method with one parameter and call it from  `class2` method.

**Sample code class2**

```
public class Test2 {
    static void Test2(){
        new Test1().show("Pass String to class1 show method");
    }
}
```

here you can pass your `string` value.